# How to find from which row and column the value belong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, indexing

Suppose I created the below data frame

```
data = {'Height_1': [4.3,6.7,5.4,6.2], 
        'Height_2': [5.1, 6.9, 5.1, 5.2], 
        'Height_3': [4.9,6.2,6.5,6.4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Suppose someone comes and asks me

1. Find the row and column of height 6.9 ?
2. Find in how many rows and columns height 6.2 is present ?

Please help me with what will be the code for this?

Comment: Can you share a your dataframe? Also share sample input and expected output.

Comment: And what is the reason for shouting like that?

Comment: I have edited my question for a better understanding @MayankPorwal . Please help me with what will be the code?

Comment: @ShripadKumar Please share the expected output and format.

Comment: The output should be like 6.9 is in (2,2) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boolean indexing, we can try something like

```py
>>> df[df == 6.9]

Height_1  Height_2  Height_3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       6.9       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

However, this won't necessarily give you the exact rows and column indices of the data you're looking for. If you want to get the rows and columns explicitly, we need to do some more work.

```py
>>> bool_df = df[df == 6.9]
>>> list(bool_df.stack().index)

[(1, 'Height_2')]
```

As for the second question, we can use the `count` function, combined with the boolean approach we used earlier.

```py
>>> df[df == 6.2].count()

Height_1    1
Height_2    0
Height_3    1
dtype: int64
```

To count the rows, we can use the `axis` argument.

```py
>>> df[df == 6.2].count(axis=1)

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

To obtain the simple total count of occurrences of a certain value, we can use NumPy's `sum` function.

```py
>>> np.sum(df[df == 6.2].count())

2
```